# Laravel - Can't load picture to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I made a profile image upload for users and tried to copy the code and make the same for the custom icons users have on their links. The problem occurs when the name of the uploaded image needs to update in the database.

This is code I copied from UserController:

```
    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->fit(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['success' => 'Profile picture updated!']);

    }
```

Here is code I am trying, but failing in LinkController:

```
    public function custom_icon(Request $request){

        if($request->hasFile('icon')){
            $icon = $request->file('icon');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $icon->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($icon)->fit(300, 300)->save( public_path('/img/icons/' . $filename ) );

            $icon->icon = $filename;
            $icon->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['success' => 'Custom icon uploaded!']);

    }
```

And here is part of my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', ], function() {

    Route::get('/links', [LinkController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'create'])->middleware('verified');
    Route::post('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::post('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::post('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'custom_icon']);

    Route::get('/qrcode', [UserController::class, 'qrcode']);

    Route::get('/settings', [UserController::class, 'settings']);
    Route::get('/settings/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::get('/settings/profile', [UserController::class, 'profile']);
    Route::get('/settings/qr', [UserController::class, 'qr']);
    Route::post('/settings/edit', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    Route::post('/settings/profile', [UserController::class, 'update_avatar']);
    Route::post('/settings/qr', [UserController::class, 'qr']);

    Route::get('/settings/vcard', [UserController::class, 'vcard']);
    Route::get('/settings/vcard/name', [UserController::class, 'vcard_name']);
    Route::get('/settings/vcard/contact', [UserController::class, 'vcard_contact']);
    Route::get('/settings/vcard/info', [UserController::class, 'vcard_info']);

    Route::get('/settings/help', [UserController::class, 'help']);
    Route::get('/settings/help/devices', [UserController::class, 'devices']);
    Route::get('/settings/help/account', [UserController::class, 'account']);
    Route::get('/settings/help/terms', [UserController::class, 'terms']);

    Route::get('/settings/help/contact', [ContactController::class, 'contact']);
    Route::post('/settings/help/contact', [ContactController::class, 'send_email']);

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The problem occurs" - what does that mean? How is your problem related to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: You are right PhpMyAdmin has nothing to do with this even though I am using it, I will remove the tag.

Comment: Feel free to share more details. You haven't explained yet which problem you are facing

Comment: When I try to upload an image and add it as a link icon, the image gets to desired file directory and name updates but in the database, nothing happens. It should update the database to the image name.

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can update user table directly for update user table by directly by eloquent

```
user::where('id',Auth::id())->update(['avatar'=>$filename])
```

Comment: I am updating the link table not the user table, that's where my problem is. When I was updating the user table for the profile image I was using this code 

`$user = Auth::user();
  $user->avatar = $filename;
  $user->save();`
but 
`$user = Auth::user();`
does not work for the link controller.